# SVN Tortoise Icons not showing

Tags: svn, registry, wamp, tortoisesvn, wampserver

[Updated]
I have SVN configured in my ServerA

Now I access with my laptop to the server, typing for example in my folder location:

\ServerA\www

The parent folder says that everything is updated: http://prntscr.com/lq6ctl

But inside I have a file to commit: http://prntscr.com/lq6d7c

Why is it not working at parent folder?

Comment: Did you restart your laptop after the installation of TortoiseSVN?

Comment: @royalTS yes. I restarted the laptop and the servers. I open the server folder: \\ServerA\www and there are no icons :(